# Live preview of changing image file

Tags: software-recommendation, preview, image-editing, image-processing

I'm looking for a software recommendation that will allow me to view an image file that changes frequently, that ideally updates the display within 1 second after the file changes on disk.

Why? I'm working with a tool that generates images, and I want to rapidly test out different options. But it's frustrating to open and close the image after every single change. I'd rather just devote half my monitor to showing what the image looks like right now (latest version on disk) and the other half to working on my image generator.

I've already tried using macOS Quick Look, but it only picks up the first change. After that it doesn't show any more changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the image file in a folder such that it is the only file in the folder. Whenever you generate a new image save it with the same name to the same folder. Then with the finder window open, have the file viewed using the 3rd view icon. See image below. My image file is a simple plot.

[image]

Whenever you generate a new image and replace the old image with new image the view will automatically update.

Comment: That works pretty well! A little fragile -- the thumbnail prefers to go back to a small size if I resize or touch the window -- but totally answers my question.

Comment: Thank you!  I hope you can use this. it works well for me.